# Why maven-surefire-plugin needs to be defined for the tests to be run

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

If I call `mvn install` for example, the test phase being located before in the hierarchy should be executed. However it seems not to be the case.

I actually need to specify it manually: `mvn test install` in order for my tests to be executed.

OR

Respecifying the surefire plugin in the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4.2</version>
</plugin>
```

The test phase is supposed to call the maven-surefire-plugin which is a core plugin.
This behavior doesn't seem consistent to me. Am I missing something ?

EDIT: I am using Maven 3.2.1

Comment: Which maven version is used?

Comment: @lkrnac I am using Maven 3.2.1

Comment: Please show your complete pom file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maven version I am using (3.2.1) embeds the version 2.12.4 of the maven-surefire-plugin.
My project was a study case and had no test classes in it.

The 2.4.2 version of maven-surefire-plugin must fetch by default the Test reports even if no test class is encountered. The 2.12.4 seems not to behave this way.

When I was specifying the maven-surefire-plugin, I was overriding the plugin definition to the version to 2.4.2.

My apologies for having taken your attention for such an edge case and also with a lack of details.